# Notes 6: Anyway to access the Lotus Notes server console via Telnet/SSH/WMI/Powershell?

Tags: powershell, automation, console, lotus-notes, remote-access

I'm trying to automate a lot of tasks at my new company using Powershell. So far, I've had a lot of success with their server and network monitoring, but one thing that alludes me is whether they is any way to get into the server console of Notes 6 without going through the Notes Administrator program. I would love to be able to telnet/ssh in via powershell and send the commands I need and retrieve the results like I do with our routers, or to be able to access wmi like we do with our windows servers.

Anyone know if there is a port or setting that I am missing to gain access to this beast? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code, not quite powershell, but it is vbscript. So you could reuse the OLE calls. The script does require jconsole (so make sure that's working first). Also it uses the Wscript.shell object to send keys to the app.

I also think you may need to reconfigure Domino to accept connections from remote service controllers. The switch (from memory) is -jc, you'll need to amend the command line for your startup script (or "Path to executable" if you're running it as a Windows Service).

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/tips0439.html